# NoClassDefFounError:AndroidWebDriver. Everything seems fine in eclipse Projects. How Can I get rid of this error?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, webdriver

1. I am trying to follow the instructions at 
   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver and implement the AndroidWebDriver.
2. I imported those projects in Eclipse and made sure that there is no error; however, 
   while executing the script (SimpleGoogleTest), I get the above-mentioned Error.
3. I am attaching the screenshot with this question.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you had simply created the .apk file. You need to include the server-standalone.jar in the export path of the created apk file

Comment: QATEST, Thanks for the response. Can you please elaborate "export path of created apk file". I tried to google it. Also, tried to include that jar file in build path and selected the same in order and export in eclipse. It did not work. It will be really helpful if you can give step by step instruction.